# Toolbar missing when asking and editing questions

Tags: support, toolbar

My toolbar is missing on StackOverflow when I ask or edit a question.  It is fine for Meta, Superuser and ServerFault.

This is only happening in Firefox (I checked in IE and it was there).

I have tried restarting firefox (I checked to make sure the process was completely gone).

What I can I do to get it back?

[image: MissingToolbar]

Comment: did you try starting Firefox in safe mode? Did you try hard-clearing your browser cache (ctrl+f5)?

Comment: They same problem occurs with Chrome. Though I don't know if this might come from the extensions.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - Hard-clearing the cache did it (I did not know that trick).  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem whenever I am logged in.